# Firefox Not Displaying Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, tapestry

I have an odd issue. I have a site that is displaying slightly differently in Firefox vs Chrome.

Here is how it looks like in **Firefox:**
[image: Firefox Screenshot]

and here is how it is suppose to look like, in **Chrome:**
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

I have both of tag for the dropdown highlighted in Chrome and as seen in Firefox, it is also in the HTML. I am not sure why it is being completely excluded from the browser. I know it is not on the page because if I am in the textfield in Chrome and I press tab it goes to the dropdown whereas in Firefox it goes straight to the search button (magnifying glass) after tab.

I have tried starting Firefox in safe mode and I have made sure all of my tags are closed.

Also note (unsure if related or not) the page is broken down by components and put together using Tapestry. I am still familiarizing myself with Tapestry so I am not sure if that is involved in the solution or not but thought it would be worth to note.

**UPDATE**

Per @Bob's suggestions I have changed `-webkit-inline-box` to `inline-box` and it seems to have worked, but in reverse (it made the Chrome working version into the Firefox version).

Here are the updated screenshots.

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox Update]

**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome Update]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. It doesn't look like you have highlighted the same select element in each image. There are 2 selects in each, after all.

Comment: Oops. I double checked and highlighting the correct one in Firefox still doesn't highlight anything. The one that I am highlighting in Firefox is the other dropdown menu as seen in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the 2nd select is not displaying in Firefox because you have "display: -webkit-inline-box", which is webkit-specific (honored by Chrome, not Firefox). Try using inline-block instead.

Comment: I have tried using `inline-box` and it definitely made them look the same.. haha. Updated my question with your answer suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, duh, it should be inline-block, not inline-box